# Send extra click when clicked in python

Tags: python, automation, onclick

I am making an autoclicker that basically clicks the mouse if the user clicks. So each 1 click will be counted as 2 clicks. Here is my program so far:

```py
from pynput import mouse
from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button

mouseobj = Controller()

pressedy = False
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global pressedy
    if(pressedy):
        pressedy = False
        return
    else:
        if(pressed):
            mouseobj.click(button)
            pressedy = True

# Collect events until released
with mouse.Listener(
        on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()

# ...or, in a non-blocking fashion:
listener = mouse.Listener(
    on_click=on_click
)
listener.start()
```

When I ran this I clicked the mouse once and it started spamming multiple clicks without stopping. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out the on_click event fires once when the key is pressed and once when it is released thats why:

```py
from pynput import mouse
from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button

mouseobj = Controller()

pressedy = False
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global pressedy
    if(pressed):
        if(pressedy):
            pressedy = False
            return
        else:
            mouseobj.click(button)
            pressedy = True

# Collect events until released
with mouse.Listener(
        on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()

# ...or, in a non-blocking fashion:
listener = mouse.Listener(
    on_click=on_click
)
listener.start()
```